# Jstl working with scriptlets

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

```
<%! int x=5; %>


        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${x eq 5}"><p>hello1</p></c:when>            
            <c:when test="${x gt 10}"><p>}hello3</p></c:when>
            <c:otherwise>Value is ${x},Not hello</c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
```

Why above code is giving output of not hello from my jsp page?why it is not giving hello1 as output?

Answer (score 3):

Because `${x}` doesn't evaluate local and instance variables. It looks for a page-, then request-, then session-, then application-scoped attribute named "x". The code above would work if you used

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("x", 5) %>
```

or, much cleaner since scriptlets should be avoided:

```
<c:set var="x" value="5" />
```